# What is the difference between nullptr and nullptr_t in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, nullptr

Which one should I use? Any advantages if I use one over the other?

Comment: `nullptr_t` is the type of `nullptr`

Comment: `nullptr` and `nullptr_t` are never interchangeable. The question makes no sense. There's no such matter as choosing which one to use.

Comment: There was a [very good answer](http://qr.ae/74om57) on the same question submitted on Quora earlier today by Brain. Not sure if you're the one who asked it as it seems very coincidental.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`nullptr` is the constant, `nullptr_t` is its type. Use each one in contexts where you need respectively a null pointer, or the type of a null pointer.

Answer (score 9):

> *"... if I use one over the other?"*

You can't (*use one over the other*) they're orthogonal by these means:

`nullptr_t` is the **type** used to represent a `nullptr`

`nullptr` is <sup>(1)</sup>effectively a **constant** of type `nullptr_t` that represents a specific compiler implementation defined value.

See the [C++11 standards](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf) section:

> #### 2.14.7 Pointer literals
>
> 1. The pointer literal is the keyword `nullptr`. It is a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.
>      [ Note: `std::nullptr_t`
>      is a distinct type that is neither a pointer type nor a pointer to member type; rather, a prvalue of this type is a null pointer constant and can be converted to a null pointer value or null member pointer value. See 4.10
>      and 4.11. — end note ]

---

<sup><sup>1)</sup> Just like the `this` keyword `nullptr` stands for an rvalue rather than being of `const` type. Thus, `decltype(nullptr)` can be a non-`const` type. With Visual C++ 2015 and MinGW g++ 5.1 it is non-`const`.</sup>

Answer (score 7):

In exactly the same way that `true` is a C++ keyword literal of type `bool`, `nullptr` is a C++ keyword literal of type `std::nullptr_t`.

Answer (score 5):

`nullptr` is of type `nullptr_t`.

Answer (score 3):

If you try this

```
cout << typeid(nullptr).name() << endl;
```

you will see that nullptr is of type std::nullptr_t.

Answer (score 3):

`nullptr` is a pointer literal of type `std::nullptr_t`. 
And moreover `nullptr` is also a keyword of the C++ the same way as boolean literals false and true.:)

Answer (score 3):

From [lex.nullptr]:

> **Pointer Literals**
>
> *pointer-literal*:
>        `nullptr`
>
> The pointer literal is the keyword `nullptr`. It is a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. [ Note: `std::nullptr_t`
>   is a distinct type that is neither a pointer type nor a pointer to member type; rather, a prvalue of this type is
>   a null pointer constant and can be converted to a null pointer value or null member pointer value. See 4.10
>   and 4.11. —end note ]

So use `nullptr` when you need a pointer literal, and `std::nullptr_t` in a context when you need to take that type. The latter, for instance, if you're making a function or constructor or something that can take a `nullptr` as an argument.